# Overlapping elements in both directions

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Guys I'm trying to recreate this site, just for a learning purpose,
and in the News section of the home page, there's this card with
a hover effect. Is it possible to pull out that just with css ?
I always end up with that slide out half behind the next card.
Different `z-index` on each card would work, it's just that last one
is sliding out in the 'wrong' direction.
Here's the sites link https://altar.io/

Comment: Can you include a minimal and complete example with code here in the question? And more clearly explain the issue you're experiencing, what you've tried to solve it, and what your expected outcome/behavior is?

Comment: Hey Marko, there is a way of learning how they work. just check them out inside your browser's console. it contains helpful info about each and every element on the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the website you're trying to re-create uses wow.js which generates animations with JS and CSS.

you can get it from here:
https://wowjs.uk/docs

you can check the library by just looking at the DIV element of each card. they contain a data attribute like `data-wow-duration` which is a `wowjs` library codes